# R-Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am trying to apply the dplyr package and calculate the number of entries for each card number in a dataset with the following function:

```
freq<- function(data){
  data <- complete.dupremoved[order(-complete.dupremoved$SUMMA),]
  aggregate(count ~., data=transform(complete.dupremoved,count=1), length)
  complete.dupremoved$count <-complete.dupremoved[complete.dupremoved$KLIENDIKAARDINR,]
  sample <- count(complete.dupremoved, vars = "KLIENDIKAARDINR")
  complete.dupremoved<- merge(complete.dupremoved,sample, by ="KLIENDIKAARDINR")
  return(complete.dupremoved)
}
```

The error shown is Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists.

When I do the :
lapply(complete.dupremoved,class)

Some columns are numeric , factors , character , integer. Any solution how to solve this?
Also the debugger gives the following:

```
function (x) 
{
    stopifnot(is.list(x))
    if (length(x) == 0) {
        x <- list()
        class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
        attr(x, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(0)
        return(x)
    }
    names_x <- names2(x)
    if (any(is.na(names_x) | names_x == "")) {
        stop("All columns must be named", call. = FALSE)
    }
    ok <- vapply(x, is_1d, logical(1))
    **if (any(!ok)) {
        stop("data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists", 
            call. = FALSE)**
    }
    n <- unique(vapply(x, NROW, integer(1)))
    if (length(n) != 1) {
        stop("Columns are not all same length", call. = FALSE)
    }
    class(x) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
    attr(x, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(n)
    x
}
```

Comment: Can you give a small example of your data to reproduce the error?

Comment: 'factor'-vectors are not atomic.

Comment: @42-, but `is.atomic(factor("a"))` returns `TRUE`..?

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I thought vectors with extra attributes were not "atomic". Notice that `is.vector( factor("a") )` returns `[1] FALSE`. So following this quote from the `?is.atomic` page: "It is common to call the atomic types ‘atomic vectors’, but note that is.vector imposes further restrictions: an object can be atomic but not a vector (in that sense)." I hereby modify my comment to "factors are not atomic vectors".

Comment: @42-, that's interesting. I also just learned that it's impossible to do `vector(mode = "factor", 0)`. Anyway, regarding the error message, it's probably not related to factors since `data_frame(x = factor(1))` is allowed.

Comment: This is an example of the data:

   TSEKK_ID        KPV      KPV_ID     KELL SUMMA KLIENDIKAARDINR
 2.014011e+23 2014.01.12 20140112 18:42:05  2.75     9.23366e+15
 2.014011e+23 2014.01.12 20140112 18:42:33  3.21     9.23366e+15
 2.014011e+23 2014.01.12 20140112 18:43:29  7.99     9.23366e+15
 2.014011e+23 2014.01.12 20140112 18:46:07 -0.59     9.23366e+15


  customerdata(KPV+KELL+KLIENDIKAARDINR)
 2014.01.1218:42:059233660018360314
 2014.01.1218:42:339233660016101200
 2014.01.1218:43:299233660015725808
 2014.01.1218:46:079233660016361066

Comment: @42 yes the is.atomic(factor("a")) does return a TRUE.

Comment: @docendo discimus
I have added the debugger code.Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether a factor is an atomic vector (and it is not). What matters is the code for 'is_1d'.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this error is that the function is creating a dataframe as a variable within the original dataframe. This is the line that does that:

```
complete.dupremoved$count <-complete.dupremoved[complete.dupremoved$KLIENDIKAARDINR,]
```

In future you can check your dataframe with this to identify the class of each variable:

```
sapply(your_df_here, class)
```

The main question aside, I hope you were able to calculate entries by factor. There are several existing options out there.